# Add items to cocos 2dx scroll view

Tags: cocos2d-x

How can I add items to cocos 2dx scroll view ? The following code is for creating the scrollview.

```
      _scrollView = cocos2d::extension::CCScrollView::create(CCSizeMake(posW, 1000));
        _scrollView->setPosition(posX, posY);
        _scrollView->setDirection(cocos2d::extension::kCCScrollViewDirectionVertical);

        _scrollView->setVisible(true);
```

I don't know how to proceed further. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: setContentNode perhaps? The content node contains all the child nodes you need in the scrollview

Comment: the real problem is I don't know how to add items to setContentNode. :)  I modified the code as below                                      cocos2d::CCNode *pContainer = new CCNode();
            _scrollView->setContainer(pContainer);  Nothing is showing. Please provide me one sample code

Comment: the ccnode itself does not draw anything, try adding a sprite to pContainer

Answer (score 1):

```
_scrollView->addChild(yourNode);
```

This automatically places the nodes in the scroll views container because scroll view overrides the addChild method from node.